# WiEngine Tutorials

Tags: android, game-engine

I was wondering are there any good English written tutorials on WiEngine for android?

I'm getting frustrated from the Chinese language, and not all translations from Chinese to English make sense all the time :(

Comment: While I don't know of any English tutorials on WiEngine, I do know their is a graphics engine called AndEngine you could check out (written in english :>). http://www.andengine.org/. Do you have specific reasons for using WiEngine?

Comment: I guess AndEngine is fine, it has a good community and so, but the owner Nicolas is at Zynga now, and I don't believe he'll work on it for future updates, beside WiEngine demo is absolutely stunning compared to AndEngine, and shows lots of potentials.

Comment: This may be useful: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/mobile/Create-Android-AngryBirds-Game-Using-WiEngine-SDK-Part-1.aspx

Comment: @vikasde thank you, sounds very promising, I'll check it out.

Comment: I would suggest you check out cocos2d-x. There's plenty of English-language documentation and tutorials ([here's one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started)) and it's also based around cocos2d, but cross-platform for iOS, Android, Bada, Windows and more.

Comment: This type of questions are suitable in chat.stackoverflow.com, SO is meant for realtime programming QnAs.. For suggestions on reference materials, tutorials, software tools you can go for chat.. Am sure you will get help.

Answer (score 4):

Now it's opens source, you can view the code and there are several wikis. There will be more:
https://github.com/stubma/WiEngine